# Set cookie and redirect after element click

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to add dummy log in feature to my express 4 app.
I have two elements and I want to set different cookie after one of this elements is clicked (cookie depends on clicked element e.g. A and B).

I tried with socket.io events. Redirect works but setting a cookie is, as I read somewhere, impossible.

I'm super beginner in express so I don't have any other ideas.
I'm also trying to make it single page application so redirects with different url are not welcome. I'm rather want to res.render everything but I don't know if it's even possible.

UPDATE
Creating hidden form works well but it looks like some dirty hack

Comment: Are you using Angular for UI ?

Comment: Nope. I try to keep it as small as possible. Nodejs + Express + (maybe) socket.io

Comment: If you want I can explain login flow with Angular ..with cookie settings...

Comment: Thanks but I don't need such bulky tool like Angular. But you can tell me is my solution with hidden form dirty hack or acceptable solution.

Comment: Can you show how are you setting the cookie right now?